# SequenceType / GeneratorType That Can Also Throw?

Tags: swift, sqlite, swift2

I'm in the process of learning Swift and as an exercise, I'm writing a wrapper around SQLite. As I was experimenting, I realized that for queries that return rows (like SELECT), I could implement the SequenceType / GeneratorType protocols so that I can return a set of data for each sqlite3_step that I perform.

In practice, sqlite3_step either returns a row or is done, but in theory, it could error out. I'm not doing anything crazy with SQLite. It's just a simple data store for me, so I'm not rewriting schemas on the fly or potentially ripping the database out from under itself, but the fact remains that IN THEORY sqlite3_step could fail.

The question then is, is there a proper way to handle errors in the SequenceType / GeneratorType pattern? GeneratorType's next method doesn't support a throws parameter and returning nil just dictates the end of a sequence. Would there be a good way to handle the error and propagate it up the chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options, depending on what you're looking for.

If you need the Sequence to be lazy, you could use a ResultType kind of thing:

```
enum SQLiteRow<T> {
  case Success(T), FailureTypeOne, FailureTypeTwo
}
```

Then, your `next()` method would return a `SQLiteRow<T>?`, where `T` is the type of your row.

This fits in nicely with for-loops, as you can use it like this:

```
for case let .Success(row) in queries {...
```

so the successful queries are bound to the `row` variable. This is only if you want to filter out the failed queries. If you wanted to stop everything, you could switch within the for loop, or have a function like this:

```
func sanitize<
  S : SequenceType, T where
  S.Generator.Element == SQLiteRow<T>
  >(queries: S) -> SQLiteRow<[T]> {
  var result: [T] = []
  result.reserveCapacity(queries.underestimateCount())
  for query in queries {
    switch query {
    case let .Success(x): result.append(x)
    case .FailureTypeOne: return .FailureTypeOne
    case .FailureTypeTwo: return .FailureTypeTwo
    }
  }
  return SQLiteRow.Success(result)
}
```

That will take a sequence of possibly-failed queries, and give back either a sequence of successful queries (if none failed), or a failure type representing the first failure it came across.

However, the second option there *isn't* lazy. Another eager way to do it would be to use `map`, which (as of the latest beta) can take a closure which throws:

```
func makeQuery(x: String) throws -> String {
  return x
}

let queries = ["a", "b", "c"]

do {
  let successful = try queries.map(makeQuery)
} catch {
  // handle
}
```

Unfortunately the lazy version of `map` *doesn't* throw, so you have to evaluate the whole sequence if you want to throw like this.

Comment: That's what I figured would be the solution, but since throw has become the new standard for error checking, I wasn't sure if I could do something with it. All of my original Swift 1 code used enum returns for value / error.